# React Query - How to always refetch data on first entry and cache it until page reload?

Tags: caching, react-query

I don't really like the approach of displaying potentially incorrect data to the user (stale)
until the new data arrives.

I prefer re-fetching the data always when the user first enters the page,

and then caching it until he performs a reload to the page or enters it again.

I can't find a solution using react-query, does anyone knows how to do so ?

thanks!

Comment: React-query will refetch on page reload anyways. What do you mean by "I can't find a solution"?

Comment: I cant find a solution to the entire flow I described. I mean, I don't want to display data from the cache when the user first enters the page, but I do want to display cached data after the first request, until a page reload.

Answer (score 3):

React Query returns an `isFetchedAfterMount` flag that can be used to ignore stale data. If you have `refetchOnMount: 'always'`, you can render a loading spinner or whatever as long as `!isFetchedAfterMount`.

Comment: Cool, but I guess I should combine it with some additional flags in order to achieve the exact behavior I want right ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the "behaviour you want". If you just want fetch once, then never again until the user closes the browser tab, set `staleTime: Infinity`.